# Not able to return the data

Tags: node.js

I am not able to return mainData in the below code. But when i console it it is printing the mainData.

```
apiRoutes.get('/cookList', function(req, res) {

    var mainData = [];
    Save_Food_Detail.find({}, { userID: 1 }, function(err, docs) {

        if (err) {

            res.send({
                success: false,
                msg: 'some error occured',
                data: null
            });
        } else if (!docs) {

            res.send({ success: false, msg: ' data not available in this time', data: null });
        } else {
            var j = 0;
            //  var mainData[j];
            for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {

                UserData.find({ userID: docs[i].userID }, { name: 1, email: 1, mobile: 1, userID: 1 }, function(err, cookdata) {

                    if (err) {
                        res.send({
                            success: false,
                            msg: 'some error in userData',
                            data: null
                        });
                    } else {
                        mainData[j] = cookdata[0];
                        console.log("cookData", mainData);
                        j++;
                    }

                });
            }
res.send({success:true,msg:"data retrieved succesfully", data:mainData});
        }


    });


});
```

Comment: You can't use async functions inside a for loop. Use `Promise.all` or the `async` library.

Answer (score 0):

`UserData.find()` is asynchronous which means that your `res.send()` is occurring before the lookup happens. You need to process all of the callbacks before you call the response.

The easiest way to do this is with Promises.

```
const promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
  promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    UserData.find(..., function(err, cookdata) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      // add to array or whatever
      return resolve(cookdata);
    }));
  });
}
Promises.all(promises)
.then(function() {
  // res.send() here
});
```

Comment: Yup. My thought was right. I had implemented the same thing. I just wanted to know whether this is the right way of solving it. Thanks @doublesharp :) . I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

```
var async = require('async');
...
apiRoutes.get('/cookList', function(req, res) {
    Save_Food_Detail.find({}, { userID: 1 }, function(err, docs) {
        function send(msg, data) {
            res.send({success: (!data), msg, data: data || null})
        }

        if (err) 
            return send('some error occured');

        if (!docs)
            return send('data not available in this time');

        function getUser(doc, callback) {
            UserData.find({userID: doc.userID}, {name: 1, email: 1, mobile: 1, userID: 1}, callback)
        }   

        async.map(docs, getUser, function(err, users) {
            if (err)
                return send('some error in userData')

            send('data retrieved succesfully', users.map((u) => u[0]));
        })
    });
});
```